# How to check the identity of the person who added a Google Doc comment

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to create a add-on that processes all the comments added by the user in a Google Docs document. I can use [Drive.Comments.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments/list) to get the list of all comments in the doc and [Session.getEffectiveUser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getEffectiveUser()) to get the identify of the user running the script.

I tried filtering by email address. However, the results of `Drive.Comments.list` do not include author.emailAddress. [Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments/list?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%221VLZht8z8WIIP28ijvLWzLpdn1UvtwrhtTmGW3NZNIdQ%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22comments(author(displayName))%22%7D) is an example to show that `displayName` is included. [Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments/list?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%221VLZht8z8WIIP28ijvLWzLpdn1UvtwrhtTmGW3NZNIdQ%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22comments(author(emailAddress))%22%7D) is an example that shows that `emailAddress` is not included. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments#resource) for `emailAddress` does say `This may not be present in certain contexts if the user has not made their email address visible to the requester.` However, `emailAddress` is not present even for comments added by the user running the script. And so filtering by email address does not work.

I then tried filtering by display name. However, `Session.getEffectiveUser` does not provide a way to get the display name. Is there any other way to get the display name of the user running the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [about.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get) This returns the users email address.

```
{
  "kind": "drive#about",
  "user": {
    "kind": "drive#user",
    "displayName": "Linda Lawton",
    "photoLink": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhroCYJp2P9xeYeYk1npchBPK-zbtTxzNQo0WAHI20=s64",
    "me": true,
    "permissionId": ddd88225573437243",
    "emailAddress": "xxxxx@gmail.com"
  },
```

Comment: The email address from `about.get` does not help as comments do not include the email of the comment author. However, the `displayName` from `about.get` does work.

PS: Comments do have the `photoLink` of the comment author, and that could be used as a unique id. However, I think many users who have not set their profile picture will have an empty `photoLink`. And so I am going to have to rely on matching the `displayName` which could result in rare false positive matches if two users have the same name.

Comment: This is really the best option you have.  Although if you have profile scope added to  your app you may want to consider just checking the users profile directly.